# Need to programmatically open bluetooth and discover devices in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need to open up bluetooth through my code without asking the user to enable it and then discover all the devices in range and return those devices and then close bluetooth connection.

How to do it?

Comment: "Bluetooth should never be enabled without direct user consent" http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#enable%28%29

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose here is exactly what you need.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#FindingDevices

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#DiscoveringDevices

About enabling the Bluetooth without asking the user, here is what the doc says:

> Bluetooth should never be enabled without direct user consent. If you
>   want to turn on Bluetooth in order to
>   create a wireless connection, you
>   should use the ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE
>   Intent, which will raise a dialog that
>   requests user permission to turn on
>   Bluetooth. The enable() method is
>   provided only for applications that
>   include a user interface for changing
>   system settings, such as a "power
>   manager" app.

But if you really want to Enable device bluetooth without asking the user. after add this:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

permission to your Manifest use this code in your App

```
BluetoothAdapter.enable()
```

Comment: Hey Shaunak,thanks for the reply... My one part of finding devices is done by ur link... now can u tell me how to turn on bluetooth with out sending a prompt to the user to enable it :)

Comment: @Coder_sLaY Can you please post your code here, How you are finding the devices.