# How to enable phone bluetooth programmatically, without the users permission?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm developing an android app that allows the user to control the central locking system of his vehicle, thus eliminating the need of the small remote key tag. 
But According to what I have done so far, everytime the user opens the app, his phone bluetooth has to be turned on manually, as in it asks for the users permission.

So what I need to know is, is there a way to turn on the phone bluetooth adapter programmatically, so that everytime the app is launched, the phone bluetooth will be enabled automatically.

I hope my question is clear. I'm new to the android programming field.

P.s - If you're wondering how the communication between the phone and the vehicle is done, there are some circuits and a bluetooth module connected to a microcontroller in the vehicle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to programmatically open bluetooth and discover devices in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080818/need-to-programmatically-open-bluetooth-and-discover-devices-in-android)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

```
btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (btAdapter == null) 
        {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device does not support bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            if (!btAdapter.isEnabled()) 
            {
            btAdapter.enable();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth switched ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
```

Comment: You need to enable BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission in the android manifest file.

Comment: I've read that btAdapter.enable(); will now(new android versions)  also pop up an user dialog, is this true?

Answer (score 0):

**In addition to SoulRayder's code**

You will need to add a uses permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file under app `>`manifests.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

This goes before the `<application>` tag but inside the `<manifest>` tag