# how to cancel bluetooth confimation window

Tags: android, bluetooth

In my app, if the bluetooth is disabled I programmatically enable it but then a window shows up to confirm turning bluettoth ON, and this window has two option YES and NO.

my question is, how can i programmatically turn bluetooth ON with forcing that window not to show up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable phone bluetooth programmatically, without the users permission?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681258/how-to-enable-phone-bluetooth-programmatically-without-the-users-permission)

Comment: Did you add  BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission in the android manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this by enabling `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN`  permission:

```
btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

if (btAdapter == null) {
    // Device does not support bluetooth
} else {
    if (!btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        btAdapter.enable();
    }
}
```