# Two Functions in one Button Click

Tags: android

I started program little bit in android, I have 2 items in  menu button.I call two functions enableBluetooth() and findDevice() at one click of 1st menu item .I want to call findDevice() function as soon as the enableBluetooth() function  is finished, at the same click. Is this possible?

Here is my code

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.retrieve:
        try {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                 enableBluetooth();

                 findDevice();

            }
} catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "cTrcker: Unable to retrive data. Try      again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        return true;
```

Comment: What is the behaviour with the current code?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080818/need-to-programmatically-open-bluetooth-and-discover-devices-in-android

Comment: you do it on true approach ,calling findDevice()after enableBluetooth() if not exception happen whats problem of this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See you can send intent to enable the blutooth by using this

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
 }
```

After this, onActivity result is the callback method for this intent.Then in OnActivityResult u can check the bluetooth availablity if enabled "**You can call the FindDevice()**" method there  or if it is not enabled you can intimate the user that the bluetooth is not yet enabled or something that u want.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the `findDevice()` inside the `enableBluetooth()` function ?

You can set a global `boolean` constant and check this constant in the `enableBluetooth()` function, if the `boolean` has already been set to `true` meaning that your application has enable the bluetooth, go ahead and call the `findDevice()` straightforward.

Comment: Current code he has posted is also functioning in the same way.